# Android SQLiteOpenHelper update method does not work

Tags: java, android

The following code is defined in an update method of a class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(EMAIL, user.getEmail());
db.update(TABLE_USERS, values, "_id" + " = ?",
    new String[] { String.valueOf(user.getUserID()) });
```

However, calling the method that contains this code does not update the database table row. The `db.update` method returns 1. Why isn't my update method working?

Comment: How do you determine the database didn't get updated? Are you running inside a transaction that ultimately isn't successful?

Comment: I didn't use any transaction and I know that the update isn't successful because the data file in data directory doesn't get updated.

Comment: If the update call is returning 1, then it definitely updated a row.

Comment: I think I know what's going on. The update is successful but somehow the value that's passed to the update method is stale value. I've fixed that now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The SQLite database gets created in the `data/data/*your-appname/databases/` folder.  If you want to be able to view the database, you can use this addon: [SQLiteManager plugin for eclipse](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/18/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/).  However, it will only work if you give your database name the extension `.db`

Comment: That's how I found out what's inside the db.

Answer (score 0):

db.update()  ---> return Updated rows count.